# Calculated Field with Count(field 1)/ Count(field 2)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

The image below mimics the pivot table I am attempting to create. The columns in red are created but I'm trying to add the third column through the use of a calculated field for delivery rate. I thought it would be something like:

```
= COUNT(Order Delivered)/ COUNT(Order Submitted)
```

But it is not returning the correct values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwuwl.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your pivot table navigate to the tool bar under "PivotTable Analyze" > Click on "Field, Items, & Sets" under Calculations > Select "Calculated Field".

This will allow you to insert a calculated field. Name your field in the first box "Percent" then in the formula box enter this = ('Orders Delivered'/'Orders Submitted'). Click ok and it will add it to your pivot table. Reformat the column to a percentage and it should be good to go.

[before 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzPQQ.png)

[what you were looing for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2za9F.png)

edited.

No need to have the "count" in the formula, pivot picks this up from the value field settings.